# Read array from other class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to read an array which is in ViewController-A from ViewController-B in order to fill the data of an UIPickerView which is in ViewController-B. How could I do it ?

I have tried this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31574620/7127489

But I don't know why I can't instantiate my ViewController-B as it says in order to pass my filled array to an empty array in the other class.

Any idea ?
Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you going from VCA to VCB. Are you using Segues? If yes you can pass the values in prepare for Segue method. Or are your both VC not interconnected

Comment: They are not interconnected. They are different views that come from an Tab Bar Controller.

Comment: Is the VC A in navigation controller or not ?

Comment: Then either you can save your data in NSUserdefaults and get it in VCB from there. Or as your example suggested, in your B controller create the instance of A and get the data from A. Though in case of tab bar controller i wouldn't advice that. You can also use delegates to pass your data

Comment: VC A is in Navigation Controller. How could I do it with delegates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegates to pass data (many examples of delegation here on SO) or [here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/pass-data-with-delegation-in-swift-86f6bc5d0894)
or you can do something like this:

If in navigationController:

```
if let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? UINavigationController, let yourController = navController.viewControllers[0] as? yourVC{ 
    yourArray = yourController.array
}
```

If not in navigationController:

```
if let yourController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? yourVC{ 
    yourArray = yourController.array
}
```

Comment: This fits with what I needed. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 0):

if your controller-B is seuged frome controller-A,you shuould declare a property in controller-B,and assign the value you need to controller-B when segueing.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a static variable storing the array in 'ViewControllerA', then you can access it from `ViewControllerB` using `ViewControllerA.array = [1,2,3]`.

You can set up the static variable as `static var array = [Int]()`

Answer (score 0):

You would be knowing the the index of ViewControllerB in tab bar. 
Declare an array in ViewControlleB. Like

```
var pickerData = [String]() // use appropriate type depending upon need.
```

Whenever the data in ViewControllerA get update update the data in ViewControllerB like this

```
   let vcb =  self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[index of ViewControllerB] as? ViewControllerB
    vcb?.pickerData = newData
```